# Paypal not seeing Paypal balance at checkout page

Tags: php, paypal

I am not seeing paypal balance of the user at paypal checkout page. Please explain me is it normal or do I need something in my code. I am using PayPal Rest Api with PHP.

The following is the link to my screen shot.

http://www.imagebam.com/image/554229333343993

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your link not working

Comment: PayPal isn't supposed to display the user's balance in that area; it's only telling them what source is being used for funding (account balance, bank transfer, credit card, etc). If you think there's something wrong with your code, you'll need to share the relevant code here so we can look it over.